# how can I load neural network with ros-melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm trying to combine UR5 robot with neural network.

I trained SAC with python3 and I hoped to load action obtained from SAC to apply it on ROS using python 2.
Is there any way to enable it?

Before this, I tried to load it using python.subprocess command, but it requires the conda virtual environment to implement python3 code, so I failed with it.

Thank you for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394369/how-can-i-load-neural-network-with-ros-melodic?/) by [Hwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/93639/hwang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Hwang

Working with Python 3 in Melodic is not very easy. If possible switch to ROS Noetic and you will have a smoother experience.

Refer to prior answer for a more complete explanation: #q348093

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-17**:
I would suggest the OP to take a look at either [wiki/catkin_virtualenv](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_virtualenv) or [rospypi/simple](https://github.com/rospypi/simple). Both make using Python 3 with Melodic quite doable.